# how to emulate the ctrl+v feature of other linux terminals without disabling the ctrl+v paste feature

Tags: pantheon-terminal

how do I make terminal emulate the ctrl+v feature of other linux systems without disabling the ctrl+v copy/paste feature of elementary os terminal.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Install elementary tweaks. Then go to the system settings and go to Tweaks. From there there is a terminal section where you can set it to natural copy paste.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Comment: I know how to set it to natural copy paste but that is not what I am asking for.
I need a way(command) to access the ctrl+V feature [like how it works on other linux systems] without disabling the current ctrl+V used to paste.
get it?

Comment: no we don't get it because you asume we should know how it works in other systems .... you need to provide proper information when you ask something.. get it?